# How change themes in JS without Jquery?

Tags: javascript, themes, toggle

[image]

want to add another theme for my project. have 2 : light and dark .
now i want to add another theme:navy
and i sholdnt use Jquery .

Comment: Read up on the [classList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: What do you mean by 3 classes?.   Your code block only shows `dark` & `navy`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue if *toggle* is the right word here - you usually *toggle* between two values. I supposed you want to *iterate* through values in a way - 0,1,2,0,1,2,...

or, let say you have classes
light, gray, dark, light, gray, dark

you can do so with the following:

```
const root = document.querySelector('html')
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu')

const classArray = ['light', 'dark', 'navy']
let classIterator = 0

menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
    root.classList.remove(classArray[classIterator % classArray.length])
    classIterator++
    root.classList.add(classArray[classIterator % classArray.length])
})
```

You have an array of classes (classArray) in which you have a set of values you want to iterate through - light, gray and dark.

On click, you want to remove the current class:

```
root.classList.remove(classArray[classIterator % classArray.length])
```

increase the counter:

```
classIterator++
```

and add the next class:

```
root.classList.add(classArray[classIterator % classArray.length])
```

The reason why you access the array element with:

`classArray[classIterator % classArray.length]` instead of `classArray[classIterator]` is because you don't want to get out of the bounds of the array, so you always iterate through 0 - 1 - 2, because mod operator gets you the remainder of the division.